# Triggering Parallel.For in c# with sleep

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parallel-processing, sleep

I have a Parallel.For loop which I use to peform a lot of HTTP request at a certain point when a scheduled task occurs like this:

```
 Parallel.For(0, doc.GetElementsByTagName("ItemID").Count, i => {
 var xmlResponse =    PerformHttpRequestMethod(); 
 });
```

Is there any way for me to set the loop to pause after the counter value hits 2,4,6,8,10 and so on...

so every 2 method calls it performs, sleep for 2 minutes lets say..

Is there any way I could achieve this ?

Comment: `Parallel.For` is meant for data parallelism. You are asking about throttling. Just don't use `Parallel`. Try eg TPL Dataflow and `ActionBlock<T>`. Another option is to use Rx to interleave URL events with delay events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use `Task.Delay`.

Now your method is `asyncronous` using `async/await`.

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
   int i = 0;
   while (i < doc.GetElementsByTagName("ItemID").Count)
   {
       Task.Run(() => PerformHttpRequestMethod());
       if(i%2==0){
           await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
           //or simply: 
           await Task.Delay(120000);//120000 represents 2 minutes.
       }
       i++;
    }
}
```

OR simply if you want to use `for` loop.

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < doc.GetElementsByTagName("ItemID").Count; i++)
    {
        Task.Run(() => PerformHttpRequestMethod());
        if(i%2==0){
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        }
    }
}
```

> How would this 2nd example look if I'd want to do iterations from 0 to 4 then sleep 5 to 9 and so on... ?

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < doc.GetElementsByTagName("ItemID").Count; i=i+5)
    {
        if( i%10 == 0 ){
           for( int j=i;j<=i+4;j++){                   
              Task.Run(() => PerformHttpRequestMethod());
           }
        }
        else{
           for(int j=i;j<=i+4;j++){
              await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's test the correctitude of algorithm.

`i=0` -> (0%10==0 ->true) ,then will execute `Task.Run(() => PerformHttpRequestMethod())` for i=(0,4)

`i=5` -> (5%10==0 ->false), then will execute `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))`; for i=(5,9).

And so on...

Comment: Hi @Alexandru, why do you use a while loop in this example?

Comment: yes thx for updated example. Can we use a Parallel.For like that instead of a regular for loop? This would ensure that I could lets say do a batch of 5 requests at a time and then sleep for xx minutes... Btw. how would this 2nd example look if I'd want to do iterations from 0 to 4 then sleep 5 to 9 then sleep and so on ?

Comment: 1)`"This would ensure that I could lets say do a batch of 5 requests at a time and then sleep for xx minutes."`? The response is : yes. You need to verify `if(i%5==0)` ,and. if true, then sleep for x minutes.
2)`"how would this 2nd example look if I'd want to do iterations from 0 to 4 then sleep 5 to 9 then sleep and so on ?"`. Please view my answer.(in 2 minutes I'll will update)

Comment: amazing answer, the best one so far. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: @User987,You're welcome !. I added one explanation for the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see the point of using a Parallel.For if you want to sleep for x number of minutes or seconds every other iteration...how about using a plain old for loop?:

```
for(int i = 0; i < doc.GetElementsByTagName("ItemID").Count; ++i)
{
    var xmlResponse = PerformHttpRequestMethod();
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
    }
}
```

Or maybe you want to keep track of the how many iterations that are currently in flight?:

```
int inFlight = 0;
Parallel.For(0, doc.GetElementsByTagName("ItemID").Count, i => {
  System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref inFlight);
  if (inFlight % 2 == 0)
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

  var xmlResponse = PerformHttpRequestMethod();
  System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref inFlight);
});
```

Comment: With the old loop I'd get only 1 batch of requests at a time. Using a controlled Parallel.For loop I would ensure that I'd have 10 batches of requests and then sleep for 5 mins ,and so on... All this in order to reduce CPU/Memory/Network stress

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by combining a Parallel.For and a normal for loop:

```
for(var i = 0;i<doc.GetElementsByTagName("ItemID").Count;i = i+2)
{
    Parallel.For(0, 2, i => {
        var xmlResponse =    PerformHttpRequestMethod(); 
    });
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```